# Weblinks não abrem em nova janela

Tags: joomla

Instalei a versão 3.2 do Joomla e criei os *weblinks*.
Tanto a configuração global, quanto a individual, estão marcadas para `target` uma *new window*, mas ao clicar o *weblink* só abre na mesma página.
Já limpei os temporários e nada acontece.
Onde no código posso definir o `target` de maneira "hard code", ou existe alguma outra solução para esse problema?

Comment: Você poderia postar essa parte?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um caso parecido com o seu no fórum do Joomla

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=643728

Existem três lugares onde a opção de destino deve ser alterado para "Abrir em uma nova janela" para que isso funcione:

As opções básicas de cada um Weblink

As opções básicas da categoria Weblink

As opções básicas do módulo de Weblink

Comment: Não está funcionando, já havia feito isso. a solução que encontrei foi instalar um plugin pra gerenciar.